# store UIFont as NSDictionary?

Tags: ios, nsdictionary, uifont

I want to create a UIFont object based on a dictionary store in a plist file.

Obviously I could create my own keys and use them to put the font name, family name, and point size, then use that to create the font.

But is there a standard way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "standard" here. There is no "standard" API to encode a `UIFont` as an `NSDictionary`. I'd suggest you create your own category methods for `UIFont`. One that returns a `UIFont` instance as a dictionary and another (class method) that creates a `UIFont` instance from such a dictionary.